# Changing VBA code to sort by Column B instead of what it is doing now

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I found this code on these forums. I have been trying to manipulate the code for what I need to do, but I am struggling with 1 piece. In particular, I want the parameters to be:

- Sorts by: Column B;
- Sort on: Cell values;
- Order: Largest to Smallest.

The problem I am struggling with is how to get it to sort by column B. I think it is sorting by column D at the moment; which, is the last column in the excel file I am working within. But, I need it to sort by column B, and can't figure out how to change it to do so. Does anyone know how to manipulate the code below to ALWAYS sort by column B?

```
Sub RangeSelectionPrompt()

    Dim rngStart As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngStart = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rngStart Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "User cancelled"
    Else
        Set WS = rngStart.Parent
        WS.Sort.SortFields.Clear

        With rngStart
            WS.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
                .Columns(.Columns.Count), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
                xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With

        With WS.Sort
            .SetRange rngStart
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `.Columns(.Columns.Count)` to `WS.Columns(2)`?

Comment: I love you BIGBEN. You made my day. I didn't know what to do, but you taught me a lesson.

Answer (score 0):

The key element of your `rngStart.WS.Sort.SortFields` element define how to sort the data.
With the command `WS.Sort.SortFields.Add`, you add a sorting key to the sort function. You could add several keys to it (to sort first the column A, then the column B).

Assuming the range you want to sort is starting with the column A, and you want it sorted by column B, you may want to use @BigBen solution, and set your key to `.Columns(2)`.

The next parameter of this key will let you decide how the sorting happens:  `SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= xlDescending,`. You cna understand that the sorting will be based on value. and descending. So it should be the way you want it.

You can find much more information about how the sortfield methods here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sortfields.add